# Accessing module instance in express middleware

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I'd like to have a node module, which exports a factory that returns instances of a class function.

```
//myModule.js
function MyClass(options) {
    this.options = options || {};
}

MyClass.prototype.handle = function(req, res, next) {
    //I want to access the instance here in the middleware function
    console.log(this.options);
}

module.exports = function(options) {
    return new MyClass(options);
}
```

Then, inside server.js, I'm attaching this middleware:

```
var myInstance = require("./myModule")({
    foo: "bar"
});

app.use(myInstance.handle);
```

Inside the middleware function, *this* refers to something else (the global object maybe?), but I want to access the instance containing options. The only solution I could come up with was calling `myInstance.handle.bind(myInstance)`, but that's not too friendly to the module's users. Is there another way to solve this problem, or is there a better way to do this kind of pattern entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to avoid using prototype whenever you can, and you can achieve what you're doing using something like this:

```
module.exports = function(opts) {

    // private methods/vars
    var options = opts || {};

    return {
      handle: function(req, res, next) {
        console.log(opts);
      }
    }
}
```